# Extra columns in oTree data from previous treatment

Tags: otree

In my experiment, I have three treatments. When I run the last treatment, I get columns on the previous two treatments, although these columns are blank. This is not the case when I run the other two treatments. I am unable to detect anything in the code that can lead to this and the codes run correctly. Do you have any advice for me?

Comment: It's difficult to understand your question. Could you specify it? Also: Maybe the oTree forum might be a better place to ask such questions: https://www.otreehub.com/forum/

Comment: @Poza Thank you so much for your suggestion. I will seek help from oTree forum.